# Multi-armed bandit with max instead of mean

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

Is there a term or name (or better yet, strategies) for the following problem?

Take a 'standard' $k$-armed multi-armed bandit problem (stochastic real rewards, IID pulls for a given arm), but instead of maximizing the mean sum of rewards across $H$ pulls, maximize the mean *maximum* reward across $H$ pulls.

(I know that classically this is formulated as minimizing regret instead.)

Intuitively, strategies for solving this would have substantially more variance-seeking than strategies for a standard multi-armed bandit problem - if you're in an exploit phase with sufficient pulls left and arm A is known to have a somewhat higher mean, but somewhat lower variance, than arm B, a strategy for a normal multi-armed bandit problem would likely pick A, whereas a strategy for this would likely pick B.

Comment: you may be looking for the distinction between "simplex regret" and "cumulative regret"

Comment: I went to search the term 'simplex regret' and this question was on the first page of the results :/

Comment: I am aware of the mathematical concept of a simplex; I do not see how it applies in this situation. I have changed the reward function, not the feasibility region. Please elaborate?

Comment: oh sorry, I meant to say "simple regret"

Comment: Mm. Both simple and cumulative regret are measured w.r.t. the arm with the highest _mean_ however, which may not be the optimal choice in this setting. Or am I missing subtleties here?

Comment: There appears to be a closely-related MAB variant called an Extreme Bandit - though it uses a different regret model which is not the same. (in each timestep, draw one sample from every arm and take its max. max-<actual value> is your loss in that timestep, and sum that over time.)

Comment: yeah I wasn't 100% sure what you meant by "mean maximum reward"; may be worth writing this out mathematically or just expanding on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hunting, this appears to be known as, imaginatively (/s), the Max Bandit Problem. (This is annoyingly difficult to search for, as 'max' appears in almost all descriptions of the 'standard' k-armed bandit problem.)

I have implemented the algorithm described in [Kikkawa & Ohno, 2022](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.08225.pdf), and it appears to suffice for my usecase.